# Why don’t plant cells need centrioles?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, plant-physiology, cell-division

I’ve just learned about cell division and I noted that plant cells **don’t have** centrioles but still undergo cell division. I’ve read a few documents about it and wondered why plant cells don't have centrioles.

How is it that plant cells can divide without centrioles?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It is expected that you will demonstrate that you have done some research on your own before asking questions here — a quick search turns up this: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10210/how-do-plant-cell-divide-without-centrioles ——— Please also take the time to take the tour and then the help pages starting with How to Ask questions on this site. Thanks! 